# How to use SameText for AnsiStrings in modern Delphi?

Tags: delphi, unicode, string-comparison

I need to compare two AnsiStrings to see if they have the same text (ignoring case).

```
var
  text1, text2: AnsiString;
begin
  if SameText(text1, text2) then
  ...
```

In pre-Unicode Delphi I would use `SameText` function, but in modern Delphi there is only Unicode version of it, so I'm getting this warning: `W1057 Implicit string cast from 'AnsiString' to 'string'` upon call.

My question is, how to properly compare AnsiStrings in modern Delphi without getting compiler warnings (and without superfluously having to cast both strings to `UnicodeString(text)`)

Comment: IIRC there is an ansistrings or ansistrutils unit that contains the functions for ansi strings. (No Delphi on this machine)

Comment: As @Marjan says, [`there it is`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.AnsiStrings.SameText).

Comment: The question that you should be asking yourself, is why you even want to compare two `AnsiString` variables.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I have some reasons. Maybe we can discuss that in chat? (AnsiStrings in Delphi room)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Indeed, there's an `AnsiStrings` module that keeps all the older AnsiString versions of string utils :)

So the solution is as follows:

```
uses
  System.AnsiStrings;
...
var
  text1, text2: AnsiString;
begin
  if AnsiStrings.SameText(text1, text2) then
  ...
```